# how to convert floating number to integer in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, floating-point, cat

I have a file that look like this:

```
#[1]CHROM       [2]POS  [3]REF  [4]ALT  [5]GTEX-1117F_GTEX-1117F        [6]GTEX-111CU_GTEX-111CU        [7]GTEX-111FC_GTEX-111FC        [8]GTEX-111VG_GTEX-111VG        [9]GTEX-111YS_GTEX-111YS  [10]GTEX-ZZPU_GTEX-ZZPU

22      20012563        T       C       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
         0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

I want to convert it to look like this:

```
#[1]CHROM       [2]POS  [3]REF  [4]ALT  [5]GTEX-1117F_GTEX-1117F        [6]GTEX-111CU_GTEX-111CU        [7]GTEX-111FC_GTEX-111FC        [8]GTEX-111VG_GTEX-111VG        [9]GTEX-111YS_GTEX-111YS  [10]GTEX-ZZPU_GTEX-ZZPU
    
22      20012563        T       C       0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I basically want to convert the 0.0 or 1.0 or 2.0 to 0,1,2
I tried to use this command but it doesn't give me the correct output:

```
cat dosage.txt | "%d\n" "$2" 2>/dev/null
```

Does anyone know how to do this using awk or sed command.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the logic of getting expected output, kindly do explain on same.

Comment: What if we see `0.5`? Should that be kept as-is? Rounded? Truncated?

Comment: Check this answer with awk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057902/formatted-printing-in-awk

Comment: What is `"%d\n" "$2"` supposed to mean? `%d` is a `printf` format operator, but you didn't use `printf`. `$2` is the second argument to the script, how will that get anything from the file?

Answer (score 0):

> how to convert floating number to integer in linux(...)using awk

You might use `int` function of GNU `AWK`, consider following simple example, let `file.csv` content be

```
name,x,y,z
A,1.0,2.1,3.5
B,4.7,5.9,7.0
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==1{print;next}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){$i=int($i)};print}' file.csv
```

gives output

```
name,x,y,z
A,1,2,3
B,4,5,7
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that `,` is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`). I `print` first row as-is and instruct GNU `AWK` to go to next line, i.e. do nothing else for that line. For all but first line I use [`for` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html) to apply `int` to fields from 2nd to last, after that is done I `print` such altered line.

(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)

Comment: I suggest you check first whether there is any loss with the conversion. e.g. `if($i==int($i)) $i=int($i)`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/((\s|^)[0-9]+)\.[0-9]+(\s|$)/\1\3/g;ta' file
```

Presuming you want to remove the period and trailing digits from all floating point numbers (where n.n represents a minimum example of such a number).

Match a space or start-of-line, followed by one or more digits, followed by a period, followed by one or more digits, followed by a space or end-of-line and remove the period and the digits following it. Do this for all such numbers through out the file (globally).

N.B. The substitution must be performed twice (hence the loop) because the trailing space of one floating point number may overlap with the leading space of another. The `ta` command is enacted when the previous substitution is true and causes sed to branch to the `a` label at the start of the sed cycle.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help.  This regex saves the whole part in a variable, and removes the rest.  regex can often be fooled by unexpected input, so make sure that you test this against all forms of input data.  as I did (partially) for this example.

```
echo 1234.5  345 a.2 g43.3  546.0 234. hi | sed 's/\b\([0-9]\+\)\.[0-9]\+/\1/g'
```

outputs

```
1234 345 a.2 g43.3 546 234. hi
```

It is important to note, that this was based on gnu sed (standard on linux), so it should not be assumed to work on systems that use an older sed (like on freebsd).

Comment: You are right to be cautious, remember a `*` in a regexp represent **zero** or more of the character/group preceding it. So for instance this might remove a period at the end of a sentence. The `+` guarantees one or more. Also, why the `m` flag?

Comment: @potong thanks for the correction.  There is also a case for when non numbers, like M.2, which also can be solved buy using plus.    The m was not necessary, it was just a force of habit from my multiline regex days.  I've updated my answer!